# How do you bypass the password input when making a password protected zip file?

Tags: linux, bash, zip

I know it's possible to password protect a zip file by using -e.

```
$ zip -e archivename.zip directory_name
```

After which you have to enter a password twice in the terminal. I was wondering if it's possible to bypass that by using an alias or a function so that it would look more like this:

```
$ zip archivename.zip directory_name password
```

Comment: From `man zip`: *THIS IS INSECURE!  Many multi-user operating systems provide ways for any user to see the current command line of any other user; even on stand-alone systems there is always the threat of over-the-shoulder  peeking. Storing the plaintext  password as part of a command line in an automated script is even worse.*

Comment: If you still want to take the risk, check out the `-P` option.

Answer (score 2):

```
unzip -P <enter_password> filename.zip
```

If you want to simulate key pass for example pass = 1234 you can do this:

```
echo -ne "1234\n1234" | zip -e archivename.zip
```

\n simulate Enter